# Can Emberjs computed property depends on other model property?

Tags: ember.js

I have a model:

```
app.ObjectOne = Em.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    count: null
});
```

And another model, which computed property 'SomeProperty' I want to depend on property 'count' from ObjectOne

```
app.ObjectTwo = Em.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    someProperty: function(){
      return count+5;
    }.property('app.SomeObjectController.count')

});
```

So, can I do it that way?
Or is there any other way to do it;

The main idea is that data of ObjectOne model comes after ObjectTwo, so I what to recompute property and rerender view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, the behavior you want is exactly what Ember.js can bring to you.

First, here is a very basic template:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  Here, the template is updated each time this property is updated (equivalent to bound property)
  {{App.objectTwo.someProperty}}
</script>​
```

Here is the javascript. I don't know if you really want to use an ObjectController here, but you mention it, so I have use it. An ObjectController's act as a proxy around it's `content` property. That means here that someObjectController.get('count') will try to get the `count` property from the controller itself, and if it does not exist, then the controller retrieve the `count` property  from its content.

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.someObjectController = Ember.ObjectController.create();

App.ObjectOne = Em.Object.extend({
  id: null,
  count: null
});
App.objectOne = App.ObjectOne.create({
  id: 1,
  count: 42
});
App.someObjectController.set('content', App.objectOne);

App.ObjectTwo = Ember.Object.extend({
  id: null,
  someProperty: function(){
    return App.someObjectController.get('count')+5;
  }.property('App.someObjectController.count')
});
App.objectTwo = App.ObjectTwo.create({
  id: 1
});

//in 3 seconds the count property is set to 0. You can see the template is updated
Ember.run.later(function(){
   App.objectOne.set('count', 0);
},3000);
```

Here is the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/M3727/4/

Comment: And in the case of ArrayController, what property someProperty depends on?

Comment: I mean that App.someObjectController = Ember.ArrayController.create(); And there's an array of objects in it. Does someProperty depends on any object in array?

Comment: I expect that after 5 seconds, when two more objectes are added to the oController content array, the values of {{computed}} in the view will change. But they dont.

Comment: Hum, you did an mistake in the computed, you declare obj, but you use object ;). http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/6RAY3/6/

Comment: Oh, magic! It works! =) Thank you very much. So, the preperty value to depend on is App.oController.@each

Comment: yes, ArrayController is a proxy around its content property. So when using it in {{#each}}, or here, you have to rely directly on it, not on the content. Probably you could take a could at the Api: http://emberjs.com/api/